# Confusion about ways to use JSON in ruby sinatra application

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, mongomapper, activesupport

I'm making a Ruby Sinatra application that uses mongomapper and most of my responses will be in the JSON form.

### Confusion

Now I've come across a number of different things that have to do with JSON.

1. The Std-lib 1.9.3 `JSON` class: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html
2. The JSON Gem: http://flori.github.io/json/
3. `ActiveSupport` JSON http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html because I'm using MongoMapper which uses `ActiveSupport`.

### What works

I'm using a single method to handle responses:

```ruby
def handleResponse(data, haml_path, haml_locals)
  case true
    when request.accept.include?("application/json") #JSON requested
      return data.to_json
    when request.accept.include?("text/html") #HTML requested
      return haml(haml_path.to_sym, :locals => haml_locals, :layout => !request.xhr?)
    else # Unknown/unsupported type requested
      return 406 # Not acceptable
  end
end
```

the line:

```ruby
return data.to_json
```

works when `data` is an instance of one of my `MongoMapper` model classes:

```ruby
class DeviceType

  include MongoMapper::Document
  plugin MongoMapper::Plugins::IdentityMap

  connection Mongo::Connection.new($_DB_SERVER_CNC)
  set_database_name $_DB_NAME

  key :name,  String, :required => true, :unique => true

  timestamps!

end
```

I **suspect** in this case the `to_json` method comes somewhere from `ActiveSupport` and is further implemented in the `mongomapper` framework.

### What doesn't work

I'm using the same method to handle errors too. The error class I'm using is one of my own:

```ruby
# Superclass for all CRUD errors on a specific entity.
class EntityCrudError < StandardError
  attr_reader :action # :create, :update, :read or :delete
  attr_reader :model # Model class
  attr_reader :entity # Entity on which the error occured, or an ID for which no entity was found.
  def initialize(action, model, entity = nil)
    @action = action
    @model = model
    @entity = entity
  end
end
```

Of course, when calling `to_json` on an instance of this class, it doesn't work. Not in a way that makes perfect sense: apparantly this method **is actually defined**. I've no clue where it would come from. From the stack trace, apparently it is `activesupport`:

```
 Unexpected error while processing request: object references itself
object references itself
        /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:75:in `check_for_circular_references'
        /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
        /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `block in encode_json'
        /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `each'
        /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `map'
        /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `encode_json'
```

But where is this method actually defined in my class?

## The question

I will need to override the method in my class like this:

```
# Superclass for all CRUD errors on a specific entity.
class EntityCrudError < StandardError

  def to_json
    #fields to json
  end

end
```

**But I don't know how to proceed. Given the 3 ways mentioned at the top, what's the best option for me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I didn't need to do anything special.

I had not suspected this soon enough, but the problem is this:

```
class EntityCrudError < StandardError
  ..
  attr_reader :model # Model class
  ..
end
```

This field contains the effective model class:

```
class DeviceType
  ..
  ..
end
```

And this let to circular references. I now replaced this with just the class **name**, which will do for my purposes. Now `to_json` doesn't complain anymore and I'm happy too :)

I'm still wondering what's the difference between all these JSON implementations though.